# change timeblock in react-calendar-timeline

Tags: reactjs, react-calendar, react-calendar-timeline

I use react-calendar-timeline and when I pick up my items I would like to display them between 8am and 6pm. Only I always get the full date in the gray block or also 00:00 and 04:00, which I would like to get rid of. my current situation is as in the photo:

And my component is:
[image]

The calculation is:

```
    const [visibleTimeStart, setVisibleTimeStart] = useState(moment().startOf('day').clone().valueOf());
    const [visibleTimeEnd, setVisibleTimeEnd] = useState(moment().startOf('day').add(6, 'day').valueOf());

<Timeline
                                groups={Vehicles}
                                items={Order}
                                canMove={false}
                                visibleTimeStart={visibleTimeStart}
                                visibleTimeEnd={visibleTimeEnd}
                                itemRenderer={itemRenderer}
                                timeSteps={{
                                    second: 0,
                                    minute: 0,
                                    hour: 4, // Elke 4 uur, wat resulteert in 6 blokken over 24 uur
                                    day: 1,  // Elke dag
                                    month: 1,
                                    year: 1
                                }}
                                dayLabels={dayLabels}
                                monthLabels={monthLabels}

                            />
```

Because he also has to look ahead 6 days, does anyone have experience with this or a solution?